# They followed their natural {bent | bents} - which word should be used?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> They followed their natural bent/bents and their specializations are different.

In the sentence, which word should be used, bent or bents? In some dictionaries, "bent" is defined as singular usually. But I found "bents" in practical usage.

Comment: What does "their" refer to? For some reason it seems like it should read *bend/bends*. As written it is unclear what you are talking about.

Comment: @user3169 [bent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bent) - 1. A tendency, disposition, or inclination: "The natural bent of my mind was to science" (Thomas Paine).

Comment: @ColleenV I know what *bent* means, but I can't tell if that was the meaning the OP intended.

Comment: @user3169 I don't understand. "Natural bent" is a very common collocation. "Natural bend" is only common for this context in the sense that it is a malapropism. Why would you assume that a learner really meant to use the malapropism but accidentally used the correct word? Especially when they're asking about singular/plural and not whether it's the correct word?

Answer (score 2):

In your example

> They followed their natural bent/bents and their specializations are different.

the plural would be grammatically correct to match **they** and **specializations**, however it does sound odd to a native ear

> They followed their natural **bents** and their specializations are different.

A better phrasing would be

> They **each** followed their natural **bent** and their specializations are different.